# Trying to combine 2 programs into a single one

Tags: java, arrays

So I've got 2 Mains and I'm trying to combine them to run together and struggling.  The 1st rolls a single die 6000 times and shows the results and the second rolls 2 dice 11000 times and shows the results.  What is the easiest way to combine these so they run 1 and than the other.  Programs as follows:

```
public class DieTest
{
   public static final int N = 6000;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] d = new int[7];
      for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) d[i] = 0;

      for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
      {
         int roll = (int)(6.0*Math.random() + 1.0);
         d[roll]++;
      }
      System.out.print("Rolls: " + N);
      for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
         System.out.print(", " + i + ": " + d[i]);
      System.out.println();
   }

}
```

and the second

```
public class Dice3
{
   public static final int N = 11000;

   public static int roll()
   {
      return (int)(6.0*Math.random() + 1.0);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] d = new int[13];
      for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) d[i] = 0;

      for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
      {
         d[roll() + roll()]++;
      }
      System.out.print("Rolls: " + N);
      for (int i = 2; i < 13; i++)
         System.out.print(", " + i + ": " + d[i]);
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TwoDieFor
{
  public static void main(String ... arguments)
  {
    DieTest.main(arguments);
    Dice3.main(arguments);
  }
}
```

Comment: OP's code definitely contains some problems: static members, no methods, code duplication, hard-coded values. I expected a good answer would cover at least some of them. Apparently, OP is a Java tyro. They might regard any answer here as a good practice. Unfortunately, your snippet didn't show a sight of it. You even didn't point out that it's the most straightforward way (not the best/right), and OP needs to consider other options.

Comment: Yes Andrew I hit the up arrow to thank them for giving a response, even if I may not be able to get anything from it, was that incorrect?  Also yes very much a novice at java :)

Comment: OP asked a simple question, and I answered it correctly with a few lines of code. He didn't ask for people to review his code. I do sometimes mention things like that, when I guess someone might be interested, but he asked for "the simplest way" to do this and I gave it to him/us. I don't think an answer should be denigrated because it doesn't go into unasked questions irrelevant to what is asked. @JoshSanders: No, there's nothing incorrect about the answer. You need to ensure your classes are accessible from the `TwoDieFor` class, imports or all in the default package.

Answer (score 1):

1.Create another class to combine the code. 
 2.Create 1 method for each of the 2 `main()` methods, of course with new names like `roll1()` and `roll2()` without parameters and paste inside them the code you already have.
 3.Paste also the declarations of `N` from `DieTest` and `Dice3` but **rename** the 2nd to `M` and change every occurrence of `N` to `M` in the 2nd method you created.
 4.You need also to paste the method `roll()`. 
 5.Create a new `main()` method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    roll1();
    roll2();
}
```